# append blend file in the middle of the scene

Tags: append

[image]I have an animation in a blend file.
I want to append it to a different blend file but i want it to start from the middle and not from the begging.
How do I do that?

thanks
Gil

Comment: Assuming you're talking about pure animation, one driven by keyframes alone, one way would be to load in the archived animation and remove all keyframes (in the Dopesheet) up to the frame where you want it to start.  Save that as a separate Blend file and append that into your new scene.  Move the imported keyframes to begin at the frame where they're supposed to.  The NLA editor could be another way.  I don't use it myself so I can't advise you there.

Comment: the animation is smoke animation that I would like to add in the middle of a different blend file. The smoke animation has no keyframes. I tried to change the emission  frame start but couldn't do it  because it's greyed out. when I append this file it starts from the beginning  of the other animation and not in the middle as I want

Answer (score 0):

Append smoke archive to a new file and start at a later frame -

I've just done what you're after but in an older version of Blender.  The appended smoke starts at frame 40.  Hopefully your version will do the same...

I note that your "Emission" start slider is greyed out.  Are you using particles or do you mean the

--> Domain <-- Physics Smoke "CACHE" start/end sliders?

(see pic at bottom)

A straight out 'Append' should bring everything associated with the Domain and Emitter along with them.  I've not ever noticed sliders getting greyed out.

Could it be the way you're appending?  I select the file, then "Scene" and "Scene" a second time.

With it loaded, the scene menu up top is opened and the appended file is selected.  That takes you into that file where you only have to select both the Domain and Emitter before pressing CTL-C to grab them.

Return to the new file (in scene menu) and press CTL-V to dump the smoke items into that layer or 'collection'.

[image]

Here's how this one was done...

If the smoke is being created using the --> usual <-- smoke domain and emitter and both are given 'Smoke' physics, a wall of smoke will rise inside the domain from frame 1.

You can then append the Domain and Emitter (together) into the the new file.

Delete the existing 'Blendcache' folder as both a precaution and to recover HDD space.

Run the animation in the new file.  Make sure it still works.

It will start at the same frame as the original, so open up the Domain's "CACHE" tab in the physics properties and set it's  "Start & End"  frames to those required -

[image]

(You might have to save and exit Blender and also delete the new 'Blendcach' folder, then reload  to get it start at the later frame.  (I didn't have to do that)

Comment: A further thought if you can't get those sliders back - change the settings in the original smoke file and save that as another filename - append that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a  solution: I created a new blender smoke file. Then baked it and rendered it to images.
Then I imported the rendered images as planes to the other blender file and offset the starting frame with alpha parameter.
The problem now is that the smoke images cast a shadow. I tried to import the images shadowless but then the images appear purple for some reason and I don't know how to fix it.